# Coalescing two python lists into a sorted dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Say I have these:

```
people = ['palpatine', 'obi', 'anakin']
compassion = [0, 10, 5]
```

and I wanted to merge those into a dictionary like this, with sorting showing on the compassion value in descending order.

```
{
   "obi": 10,
   "anakin": 5,
   "palpatine: 0
}
```

I can do it using:

```
dict(sorted(dict(map(lambda i, j: (i, j), people, compassion)).items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
```

It does seem a bit congested. Is there a more 'elegant' solution for this?

Comment: `map(lambda i, j: (i, j), people, compassion)` is the same as `zip(people, compassion)`

Comment: Note that before Python 3.6 you needed to use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

Comment: While Python 3.6+ dicts are insertion-ordered, order doesn't really mean much in a dictionary because you always access values by their key instead of an index. Other than to _print_ the key-value pairs in order, I don't really see the point of sorting a dictionary

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes it's often better to sort the dictionary when you need to iterate it rather than relying on inherent order. But our task is to answer the question, not to question the question.

Comment: Sorting while constructing a dictionary always makes be uneasy. Sure, this technically works, but what is preventing someone a year from now adding code someplace to insert a new item and now the downstream assumption that the dictionary is sorted is busted. If you need to read items from a dictionary in a sorted manner then apply sorted to the items when needed in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
people = ['palpatine', 'obi', 'anakin']
compassion = [0, 10, 5]
dict(sorted(zip(people, compassion), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
# {'obi': 10, 'anakin': 5, 'palpatine': 0}
```

Or with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
dict(sorted(zip(people, compassion), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
# {'obi': 10, 'anakin': 5, 'palpatine': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` the two lists, together, then use `sorted` with the number negated as the key.

```py
res = dict(sorted(zip(people, compassion), key=lambda x: -x[1]))
```

Comment: The trick of using the negative of a number for reverse sorting might not be obvious to someone who hasn't seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the tuples from the zipped combination of the two lists:

```
d = {p:c for c,p in sorted(zip(compassion,people),reverse=True)}

print(d)
# {'obi': 10, 'anakin': 5, 'palpatine': 0}
```